# How to make sure a linux kernel version includes GTP module?

Tags: kernel

How can I make sure a particular Linux kernel version includes GTP (GPRS Tunneling Protocol) module?

Answer (score 1):

The GTP (GPRS Tunneling Protocol) is split into a control plane and a user plane. While the control plane is concerned with the signaling, i.e. the establishment and tear-down of tunnels for PDP-contexts, the user plane is carrying all the user IP data inside the tunnel. osmo-gtp-kernel is an implementation of the GTP-U (user plane) inside the Linux kernel. Linux Kernel GTP-U is included in the mainline Linux kernel since version 4.7.0.<sup>**1**</sup>

Linux kernel version later than 4.7.0 is installed by default in Ubuntu 16.10 and later releases.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>**Source: [Wiki - Linux Kernel GTP-U](https://osmocom.org/projects/linux-kernel-gtp-u/wiki)**</sub>

Comment: +1 but is there a way to check that it is included (what's the name of the module - can't see it in `lsmod`)? Maybe that is a generic question :)